# I need to check the my samples came from the same distribution? I used Kolmogorov Smirnov test but I couldn't understand it

Tags: python, computer-vision

I want to know how to use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and if anyone is willing to explain what I have to do after extracting features from multiple images using CNN. With the help of these features, I need to perform a KS test and also I am willing to know if is there any other way is there.

(i took two different sample image datasets)after features are extracted by CNN(VGG16), I normalize the features and reshape the features and perform PCA and run through the KS_2samp, this is my output

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.49853515625, pvalue=1.242376011953541e-231)
```

( i took the same images dataset and split the images into different folders and run the KS_2samp test) this is my output

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.3935546875, pvalue=6.0311675891650885e-142)
```

please, tell anyone the proper procedure for the KS test (after extracting features from images to the Kolmogorov Smirnov test)

also, I am looking for (out of distribution for images) if anyone had any idea please mention it, thanks in advance.

I need to know the step-by-step process (feature extracted from images  to Kolmogorov Smirnov 2 sample test)

Comment: Could u tell us please: What is your goal (except using statistics) ?

Comment: This question is not about programming, it might be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I need to know the step-by-step process (feature extracted from images to Kolmogorov Smirnov 2 sample test)